# how can i use array in routing with react-router

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, regex, react-router

This is my routing with regex pattern by react-router.
*ItemList* component appears when the URL is `/categories/cat1` or `/categories/cat2` or `/categories/cat3` or `/categories/cat4` or `/categories/cat5` or `/categories/cat6` otherwise *NotFound* component appears.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Container >
        <Switch>

          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}  />

          <Route path='/categories/(cat1|cat2|cat3|cat4|cat5|cat6)' component={ItemList} />

          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />

        </Switch>
      </Container>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I want to use dynamic array for *ItemList* routing like this:

```
const itemCategories = ['cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4','cat5','cat6'];
```

in this path:

```
path='/categories/(cat1|cat2|cat3|cat4|cat5|cat6)'
```

Comment: Are you saying/asking how to render separate routes for these different categories?

Comment: kinda. i want to route just for cat1 to cat6. if user types something else like categories/cat7 notFound page will appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question you want to render a route that handles multiple categories.

1. Render a single path with a match parameter. This allows you to dynamically handle *any* category value.

   ```
   <Route path='/categories/:category' component={itemList} />
   ```
2. Render a single route with a path array. This allows you to handle specifically allowed categories. This results in `path={["/categories/cat1", "/categories/cat2", ... , "/categories/cat6"]}`.

   ```
   <Route
     path={itemCategories.map(cat => `/categories/${cat}`)}
     component={itemList}
   />
   ```
3. Render a single route with a path array and map in the regex. This results in `path='/categories/(cat1|cat2|cat3|cat4|cat5|cat6)'` as you were looking for.

   ```
   <Route
     path={`/categories/(${itemCategories.map((cat) => cat).join("|")})`}
     component={ItemList}
   />
   ```
4. Render a route for each category. This allows you to handle specifically allowed categories but basically duplicates the `Route` component.

   ```
   {
     itemCategories.map(cat => (
       <Route key={cat} path={`/categories/${cat}`} component={itemList} />
     ))
   }
   ```

> I want to route just for cat1 to cat6. If user types something else
> like categories/cat7 notFound page will appear.

For this I would suggest option 2 or 3.

Comment: yes. thank you. option 2 is what i wanted =D

Comment: @SMarziSM It's not a common use case, but the utility `react-router` uses for route path pattern matching *does* allow for a sort of regex. I tested it out and it does appear to work from React/JSX. I added a fourth option (option 3) that also appears to work.

Comment: i tried both (option 2 and 3) and both worked for routing but in option 2 ***match.params*** was empty in my component. i think option 3 is better . thanksss.

Answer (score 0):

You can use : to set it to a dynamic route like this:

```
<Route path="/categories/:cat" component={itemList} />
```

and then render the route according to the users choice

Or you can map the routes like this:

```
 {itemCategories.map(route => {
             return <Route path=`/categories/${route}}` component={itemList}/>
           }}
```

I'm not sure what you want so I gave both options

Comment: i want to route JUST for cat1 to cat6. in this way that you mention we should check the match params in the component but i want to handle it in app.js with regex.

Comment: Then go with my section option with the map